# How does DropZoneJs manage instances?

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

I am wondering what happens under the hood when a [DropZoneJs](https://www.dropzone.dev/js/) instance is disabled with the `.disable()` or the `.destroy()` method, and that a new instance of DropZoneJs with the same name and jQuery selector is then created later :

- Does DropZoneJs implicitely reuses the same instance, as if I was re-enabling it explicitely using the `.enable()` method ?
- Does DropZoneJs creates a new instance ?

Answer (score 0):

My tests show that DropZoneJs creates a new instance.

So if you continually create a Dropzone instance with a name, disable it using the `.disable()` method, then renew the operation 10 times, this will lead the number of Dropzones objects to be 10, not 1 :-(

This can be monitored by examining the `Dropzone.instances.length` property.

This is not good for memory management. So if possible, try to re-hydrate a disabled Dropzone instance by using the `.enable()` method if you know its name.

I achieved that by storing the Dropzone instance in a JS variable.